# Minimum and maximum input voltage for boost converter for reliable operation

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'd like to know the minimum and maximum input voltage for a [MCP16251/2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005173b.pdf) boost converter for reliable operation.

Can someone tell me the input voltage range for this boost converter for reliable operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from the schematics given on p.2 of the schematic, it's 0.9V for 3.3V output, and 3V for 5V output.

And the datasheet defines a start-up voltage of 0.82V but the related note indicates that it's for 3.3V output. The datasheet also defines a minimum operating voltage of 0.35V **after** start-up. This means that, once the device starts to operate (i.e. with the minimum input voltage of 0.82V) it can work with input voltages as low as 0.35V. But, again, this is given for 3.3V output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me what should be the maximum input voltage for reliable 5V output?

Comment: @Newbie The schematic on p.2 shows a maximum of 4.2V for 5V output.

Comment: Thank you. But there's no explicit mention of the value in the Electrical table, right? So, it is expected to be 4.2V? 4.5V input voltage would not give an output of 5V?

Comment: @Newbie The DC CHARACTERISTICS table gives the upper bound of output adjustment as 5.5V but with keeping the input voltage lower than or equal to that value (because this is a boost converter). So, one can assume that 4.5V is still enough to get 5V because 4.5V < 5V, meets the condition. On the other hand, circuit example indicates a maximum of 4.2V. So it's really difficult to anticipate what will happen for 4.5V input. Personally, I wouldn't assume a reliable operation above 4.2V input for 5V output.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the datasheet says that the device will work even if Vin = Vout?

Comment: @Newbie apparently. But this is not indication of a reliable operation because as the input voltage gets closer to the output voltage the switching gets closer to stopping. Take a look at the performance curves given for different output voltages: The inputs do not get no more closer than 300 mV to the output. And as you go down through the characteristics tables you can see that nothing is given when the input is equal to output. This is an indication of that it's good to keep some margin between the input and output.

Comment: Yes, any idea on what margin would be good enough? I know that you already stated that 4.2V would be good. But I am Just curious to know how to approach and understand these scenarios.

Comment: @Newbie it's difficult to answer, believe me. If you have the chip physically then you can try and see by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start up conditions ...

[image]

And here is :
Maximum input voltage <= Vout < 5.5V

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please tell me what is the maximum input voltage that would help in getting 5V output?

Comment: Added in answer ...

Comment: So, Vin = Vout, the device, should work? Could you tell me where the datasheet, says this as the maximum input voltage?

Comment: In "Features", page 1 ... It seems to be the only "says" of this point.

Comment: When I give Vin = Vout, The output voltage is very unstable, going between 5.5V to 10V?

Comment: I have seen Vin = 4.2 V. No circuit with Vin=5.5 V ... And Vout < 6.5V max (absolute rating). However, Vin must be < 5.5 V (not equal).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144971/discussion-between-newbie-and-antonio51).